# Rails 3.1 engines migrations are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm creating a rails 3.1 engine with migrations. rake db:migration works fine inside that engine, and inside host app. But I need to include this engine into another rails engine. The second engine contains dummy app for testing, I added to application.rb of that dummy app this line:

```
require 'my_engine'
```

In the console, I can see classes from the first engine.

```
rake -T
```

give me app:my_engine_engine:install:migrations task, but when I'm run this task

```
rake app:my_engine_engine:install:migrations
```

I'm getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'railties:install:migrations'

Tasks: TOP => app:my_engine_engine:install:migrations
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can anyone help me with this trouble?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I'm find solution to my problem. 
I just needed to switch to my test app directory and to run there:

```
rake my_engine_engine:install:migrations
```

and it works as it should.

Comment: It is not clear from your answer what "test" directory you are talking about. Is it `/test/dummy` directory or is it some other test directory or is it from your main app's directory into which you want to mount your engine. What "test" directory did you mean?

Comment: I'd monkey patch your app to do this automatically (see step #3): http://pivotallabs.com/leave-your-migrations-in-your-rails-engines/

Comment: But I am getting this error `Don't know how to build task 'railties:install:migrations'`

Answer (score 1):

For `rails3` you need to `cd /test/testapp`, then `rake community_engine:install:migrations`

And that works!