# Ruby: Carrier Gem won't install migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use a Rails messaging gem called "[Carrier](https://github.com/stanislaw/carrier#readme)" written by a guy @stanislaw who seems to have a profile on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598057/stanislaw)

According to the ReadMe, the installation of his gem requires this command

```
rake carrier:install:migrations
```

However, when I tried it, I got `rake aborted`

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'carrier:install:migrations'
```

Anyone have any experience with this gem?

Routes.rb (by request from comment below)

```
DeviseMessage::Application.routes.draw do


  root :to => "home#index"
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => :show
mount Carrier::Engine => "/carrier"
```

Comment: Hey @stanislaw, would you consider answering this question? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using bundler? If so did you try `bundle exec rake carrier:install:migrations`? Also could you post your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @ScottJShea bundle exec etc produced the same result. I updated the OP with routes file.  Have you gotten this gem working before?

Comment: I have not tried it before but was going with general troubleshooting. You might have more success getting @stanislaw's input on his github page

Comment: Which version of Rails are you on? I was able to get it to run with 3.2.1.

Comment: I tried it with 3.1.1. The ReadMe said it was a 3.1 app.

Comment: @ScottJShea I installed rails 3.2.1 and was able to install migrations but then this happened. Did you have this problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494486/rails-undefined-method-paginates-per

Comment: Sigh, this has been a morass for you. Sadly I just encountered the same thing you did (could not remember from the last time so I just tried it fresh). I will investigate and put anything I find on your other thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message for an engine I'm creating, and this unanswered post came top in google.

Solution for me was to run the rake task from the test/dummy directory.

As it appears you're adding this engine to your app and getting the same error, perhaps you were trying to run the rake task from within the engine directory, rather than your app directory?

See also StackOverflow question at:
[Rails 3.1 engines migrations are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064265/rails-3-1-engines-migrations-are-not-work)